# JS how can I separately check access to webcam and microphone in Firefox

Tags: javascript

I need to know if there is a way to check access to a microphone or to a webcam for Firefox not using `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` . For example, this code `navigator.permissions.query({name : 'camera'})` works very well for Chrome, but Firefox doesn't support `camera` and `microphone` in `permission.query`.
The reason why I do not want to use `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` is that the permission modal for the camera and microphone will be shown separately if I make it like this `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})` for webcam and `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true})` for microphone. Thanks.

Comment: Probably not: that's what `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` is made for. Can't you do this: `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true })`?

Comment: But if the user gave access only to the webcam, how to show him that there is access to the webcam, but not for the micraphone

Comment: Ah, I get it now. Unfortunately Firefox's support for the Permissions API is still very rudimentary :/ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API#bcd:api.Permissions

Comment: @Terry Thank you, then I have no other solution)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for an answer, this isn't perfect but it does separate the permissions. If you want the audio permission to still fire when you deny permission to video, then take the getUserMedia function out of the promise chain.

Also, this is in coffeescript.

```
cameraAttributes = {}
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia {video: true}
.then ->
  navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
.then (devices) =>
  videoDevices = devices.filter (test) -> test.kind is 'videoinput'
  cameraAttributes = 
    videoDevices: videoDevices
  cameraAttributes
.then ->
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia {audio: true}
  .then (devices) =>
    audioDevices = devices.filter (test) -> test.kind is 'audioinput'
    Object.assign cameraAttributes, audioDevices
    cameraAttributes
  .catch (error) =>
    if error instanceof DOMException
      console.log "Audio - #{error}"
    else
      console.error error
    cameraAttributes
.catch (error) =>
  if error instanceof DOMException
    console.log "Video - #{error}"
  else
    console.error error
  cameraAttributes = 
    videoDevices: []
    audioDevices: []
  cameraAttributes
```